# Как правильно спроектировать роли в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных

Хочу создать бд, где имеется пользователь User и его роли, у каждого пользователя, в зависимости от роли — свой личный кабинет. Как правильно спроектировать бд?

Comment: Вариантов куча: создать поле в бд для хранения роли, создать таблицу в бд для хранения групп пользователей. Почитай про rbac

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать начать с такой схемы. Пример взял [отсюда](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-spring-mvc-role-based-spring-security-jpa-thymeleaf-mysql-tutorial.html). В данном примере у каждого пользователя может быть несколько ролей. И уже можно строить интерфейс в зависимости от принадлежности пользователя к определенной роли.

[image: Схема БД]